# Sorting hash with custom comparator in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a array of hashes that should be fairly simple to sort, but since I'm very new to ruby and still looking into documents I'm having issues to sort a hash that has few key value combinations but needs to be sorted based on multiple key values.

```
[{:attr1 => 3, :attr2 => 'test', attr3 => 'test2'}, 
{:attr1 => 1, :attr2 => 'test', attr3 => nil}, 
{:attr1 => 1, :attr2 => 'test', attr3 => 'test3'},
{:attr1 => 2, :attr2 => 'test', attr3 => 'test3'}]
```

So I'd like to sort it according to custom rule. And custom rule would be first take a look at `attr1` and sort according to it in descending order.

If there are same `attr1` values but one of those `attr3` is `nil` then order those with nil last.

So I think I would need to create custom comparator, or not. How can I do this with the least amount of pain?

If this was to be sorted it would look like this :

```
[{:attr1 => 3, :attr2 => 'test', attr3 => 'test2'}, 
    {:attr1 => 2, :attr2 => 'test', attr3 => 'test3'},
    {:attr1 => 1, :attr2 => 'test', attr3 => 'test3'},
    {:attr1 => 1, :attr2 => 'test', attr3 => nil}
]
```

Comment: What is `attr3`? You have to define local variables or methods before using them.

Answer (score 5):

```
array.sort_by{|h| [-h[:attr1], h[:attr3].nil?? 1 : 0]}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to split by last field and sort independently (assuming you need values with last attribute nil sorted too):

```
array.partition{|h| !h[:attr3].nil?}.map{|ar| ar.sort_by{|h| -h[:attr1]}}.flatten
```